# Query Multiple Post Types and Paginate Newly Created List

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, query, pagination

I know this has be asked several times but i cant seem to find the answer anywhere. My site has a resources page which is my archive for all resources (archive-resources.php).

I'm trying to also include blog posts as well. I'm able to add the blog posts mixed in with the resources query. The pagination also works but the problem is when it goes to page 4 it gives me a 404 error. Is there a way to make the pagination work with two post types combined?

archive-resources.php

```
<?php
                        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => array( 'post','resources' ),
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'posts_per_page' => 10,
                            'paged' => $paged,
                            'orderby' => array(
                                'date' => 'DESC'
                            ),
                            'order' => 'DESC'
                        );
                        $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                        
                    ?>
                    <?php if ( $my_query->have_posts() ): ?>
                        <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ): $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-resources', get_post_format() ); ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <!-- The pagination component -->
                    <?php 
                        understrap_pagination([
                            'total' => $my_query->max_num_pages,
                        ]); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `new WP_Query` for the main query of an archive template. WordPress has already queried the correct posts and things like pagination are based on that query. If you want to modify that query you should use the [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) to modify the main query before it is run.

The hook runs on every query that is performed, and the [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#methods) object is passed a parameter so that you can modify it. You can use its various methods to identify which query you're modifying.

To modify the main archive of a `resource` post type to also display posts your code would look like this:

```
add_action(
    'pre_get_posts',
    function( $query ) {
        if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_post_type_archive( 'resource' ) ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', [ 'resource', 'post' ] );
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Interesting! I think it worked...the only issue is that its using the default archive.php and not the archive-resources.php template i created with the pagination function. How do i get it to use that template?